# Simpler way of calculating $P\big(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i\big)$?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Is there any more efficient way of calculating $P\big(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i\big)$ than always using the Inclusion–exclusion principle as it's conventionally expressed? For large $n$ it becomes inpractical to performe calculations by hand since the amount of terms quickly become very large. I haven't encountered a situation where this happens but I'm just asking this out of curiosity. Is there any simpler function that one could plug in any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and acquire the desired value or something with matrices?

Comment: Inclusion-exclusion principle is the answer to $P[\cup_{i=1}^n A_i]$ in general and it can't be avoided. You might find it useful that if you truncate the formula you obtain upper and lower bounds for this probability, see [Bonferroni inequalites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole's_inequality#Bonferroni_inequalities)

Comment: I've never heard of these inequalities, I will look them up, thank you.

Comment: If the events $A_i$ have special properties then it is much easier.  Possibilities include being independent, mutually exclusive, or a chain of subevents